# Register CustomAction link to site settings from Element.xml from sppkg

Tags: sharepoint-online, spfx, elements-xml

Is it possible to register CustomAction link to site settings from Element.xml from SPFx package (SPPKG) in SharePoint Online?

I am able to create following using Element xml file using SPPKG;

1. Custom Lists with schema
2. Content Types
3. File provisioning to library

However, when I try adding a link to site settings using following code;

```
<CustomActionGroup Id="CustomGroup" Location="Microsoft.SharePoint.SiteSettings" Title="Group" Sequence="100" Description="" /> <CustomAction Id="CustomLinkActionId" GroupId="CustomGroup" Location="Microsoft.SharePoint.SiteSettings" Sequence="1" Title="Dashboard" Description="Dashboard"> <UrlAction Url="~appWebUrl/_layouts/15/viewlsts.aspx" /> </CustomAction>
```

Above code doesn't execute at all. The new app to be added is just stucks at adding state for a long time and finally breaks with error.

my questions above;

1. Is it possible to add
2. Anything is wrong in above code?

Answer (score 0):

According to this documentation, you can't add items to the site settings menu. You can only add ECB items and items to the command bar:

https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/spfx/extensions/guidance/migrate-user-customactions-to-spfx-extensions